# Not able to rename a folder even with write access on it in oneDrive

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

In onedrive someone has shared a folder with me via sending link. I can add/rename files/sub-folders in this folder but **not able to rename** this folder. Although I can **DELETE** this folder.

- Give permission via sharing a link

  ```
  POST /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/invite

  {
      "requireSignIn": false,
      "sendInvitation": false,
      "roles": [ "read | write"],
      "recipients": [
        { "email": "ABC@CD.COM" }
      ],
      "message": "string"
  }
  ```
- Delete call on driveitem by "ABC@CD.COM" will return successful on this

  ```
  DELETE /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}
  ```
- But rename call on driveitem by "ABC@CD.COM" will return 403 (**firbidden**)

  ```
  PATCH /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}
  Content-type: application/json

  {
     "name": "new-file-name.docx"
  }
  ```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. StackOverflow is for questions about programming errors, not general computing software.

Comment: This question *might* be on-topic for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @Airhead, I hope this makes sense now.

Comment: Much better, though I'm not an expert on this topic. so I can't really help you.

Comment: no problem, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Hi Prahash, can you confirm that you're calling Onedrive Consumer?

Comment: @Brad What do you mean by Onedrive Consumer? I'm using API from microsoft graph: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_update